# Parameters in parameters in Open Shift yaml file?

Tags: yaml, openshift

Is it possible to define a parameter in a yaml (Open Shift template) file and use it in another parameter like:

```
kind: Template
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myapp
objects:
    parameters:
      - name: FILE_VERSION
        displayName: File Version
        description: The File version
        value: 1.2.2
        required: true
      - name: FILE_NAME
        displayName: File Name
        description: The File Name
        value:  prefix:${FILE_VERSION}
        required: true
```

Right now it does not work when I read the above yaml part - ${FILE_VERSION} is not expanded.

Comment: Is this “generic” YAML? I’m asking be because some YAML using frameworks offer embedded functions for just that purpose. One example being AWS CloudFormation.

Comment: Its used for Open Shift deployment configuration templates etc.

Comment: You might want to check if OS offers this. Puppet was another example that occurred to me.

Comment: Are you using an OpenShift template or not? You cant do this sort of thing without a template.

Comment: Yes its an Open Shift template, I have updated my post.

Comment: Answer is no, you cannot use a template parameter as a part of default value of another parameter.